# How to move AddDbContext to Service Extension static class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have this code in my `Program.cs` in NET 6.

```
var idConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(idConnectionString));

var abcConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("abcConnection");
builder.Services.RegisterSqlServer<AbcDbContext>(abcConnectionString);

var xyzConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("xyzConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<XzyDbContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(xyzConnectionString));
```

How do I move these code into my Service extension class?

```
public static class ServiceExtensions
{     
    public static IServiceCollection AddDbContextServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ??

        return services;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a static class  DbContext as following:

```
 public static class DbContext
 {
    public static IServiceCollection AddCustomizedDbContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var connectionString = configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:Connectionstring").Value;
        var migrationsAssembly = "NameSpace";

        services.AddDbContext<DBContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly))
        );

        return services;
    }
}
```

Then Register it in startup :

```
services.AddCustomizedDbContext(configuration);
```